# Adding data to ObservableCollection does not update ListBox entries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a UserControl that is bound to an ICollectionView which I have implemnted to filter the underlying ObservableCollection.

```
public partial class DataStorage : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<CardData> dataStore;
    private ICollectionView cards;

    private string filter;
    public string itemsInList { get; set; }

    public DataStorage()
    {
        // Default constructor
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set the dataStore to be ICollectionView
        dataStore = new ObservableCollection<CardData>();

        // Data Add
        this.AddSample();

        // Set the collection source
        this.cards = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataStore);

        // set the filter
        this.cards.Filter = ContainsFilter;
}

// Other content here...
```

As I initialise the UserControl I add some sample data to the ObservableCollection. I then set the ICollectionView to be the default view for the ObservableCollection and assign the filer.

At this point all works as planned and as I update by TextBox control it will filter the sample data.

[Pic of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1a2F.png)

If i then call my AddSample() method again to add more data to the ObservableCollection these changes are not reflected in the UI.

```
public void AddSample()
    {
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("tesat1", false, 1, 0));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("test2", false, 2, 0));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("test3", false, 3, 2));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("test4", false, 4, 4));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("test5", false, 5, 0));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("help", false, 1, 0));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("fish", false, 2, 0));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("cat", false, 3, 2));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("tease", false, 4, 4));
        dataStore.Add(new CardData("whelp", false, 5, 0));
```

Above is my AddSample method. I have tried remaking the view and filter after each time I add more data.

```
            // Set the collection source
        this.cards = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataStore);

        // set the filter
        this.cards.Filter = ContainsFilter;
```

XAML -if relevant

```
       <TextBox x:Name="Filters" Text="{Binding Path=Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="55" Width="335" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" />
    <ListBox Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="0" x:Name="CardListBox"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cards}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCard}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=data}" Height="50" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I'm thinking I need to add an event handler for when the underlying collection has changed but what to do within this? As this is surely the same process as changing the collection when I call AddSample().

My suggestions or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've got 'Cards' set up as a property? You've only shown the field 'cards' (which you are referencing everywhere except in the binding)

Comment: First thing I'd do to debug is bind to your observable collection (as a property) - this will cut out any issues with CollectionView or filtering.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cards}"` If `Cards` is defined in your source, it might be helpful if you would include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First off I am assuming that Cards its your ItemsSource for the ListBox. Next after you add your item to Cards set the ItemSource to null and then right after set it back to cards or whatever your item source is.